# がもてる　対　にもてる (difference? ex. sentence)

Tags: questions

> あなたの国ではどんな女性がもてると思いますか。

Is this just asking what type of girls do you think are popular (in your hometown) ?

Or is it asking what type of girls you are interested in / who you like in your hometown?

誰かにもてる to be popular with someone/type of person so the different with が makes the girl/guy specific to the subject but Idk if it means they are now popular or if if its specifying who you like.

Answer (score 1):

> 誰かが持てる。 : Someone is popular
>
> 誰かに持てる。 : Being popular with someone
>
> あなたの国ではどんな女性がもてると思いますか。 : What kind of girls do you think are popular in your country?